# Atiyah-MacDonald 5.10

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation

The problem says:

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism
>   and let $f^{*}:\operatorname{Spec}(B)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ be the mapping associated with $f$.

And then comes the problem.

I am trying to solve this but i don´t know what $f^{*}$ means? and i don´t find anything previuosly in the book, maybe is something obvious but i don´t get it.

Comment: $f^*$ is canonical morphism induced by $f$.

Comment: $f^*$ is induced by $f$. In particular, $f:A \to B$ induces $f^*: \mathcal P(B) \to \mathcal P(A)$ by $f^*(X) = f^{-1}(X)$ for $X \subseteq B$. Then you restrict $f^*$ to $Spec(B) \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$ to get the map you mention.

Comment: There is really no definition in the book for $f^*$ previous to this question? Review the book.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews this induced mapping appears also in the problem 1.21, and before that there is no defition or anything like that

Comment: @Tunococ you mean $f^{*}(X)=f^{-1}(X\cap f(A))$?, because $f^{-1}(X)$ could be not defined for all $X$.

Comment: No, $f^{-1}(X)$ is defined for all $X\subseteq B$. @Dimitri $f^{-1}(X)=\{a\in A: f(a)\in X\}$. $f^{-1}$ is not a function that acts on elements of $B$, it is a function which acts on subsets of $B$.

Comment: Ok @ThomasAndrews , but it is not the same that $f^{-1}(X\cap f(A))$?

Comment: It is, I was contradicting what you said about $f^{-1}(X)$ not being defined, not that your definition wasn't equivalent. @Dimitri

Comment: Ok, @Thomas i get it now, thanks

Answer (score 3):

A definition of $f^*$ is given in Exercise 1.21.

Comment: I suggest adding the definition here to make the answer self-contained.

Comment: @ Ayman Hourieh: I suggest Dimitri asked where is the definition in the book and I pointed it.

Answer (score 1):

$Spec(B)$ is the set of primes ideals of $B$, and the same for $Spec(A)$. Thus, $f^{*}$ is naturally the pullback of a prime ideal of $B$ to a prime ideal in $A$ by $f$.

Suppose $P \subset B$ is prime, then the claim is that $f^{-1} (P)$ is prime in $A$. Suppose $f(ab) \in P$. Then, $f(ab)=f(a)f(b) \in P$. So $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ is in $P$ since $P$ is prime. So $f^{-1}(P)$ is prime.